# Requiring a checkbox to be checked

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, angular-reactive-forms

I want a button to be disabled until a checkbox has been checked using a FormBuilder for Angular. I don't want to explicitly check the value of the checkbox and would prefer to use a validator so that I can simply check `form.valid`.

In both validation cases below the checkbox is

```typescript
interface ValidationResult {
  [key:string]:boolean;
}

export class CheckboxValidator {
  static checked(control:Control) {
    return { "checked": control.value };
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-form',
  directives: [FORM_DIRECTIVES],
  template: `  <form [ngFormModel]="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(form.value)">
    <input type="checkbox" id="cb" ngControl="cb">
    <button type="submit" [disabled]="!form.valid">
    </form>`
})

export class SomeForm {
  regForm: ControlGroup;

  constructor(fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.form = fb.group({
      cb: [ CheckboxValidator.checked ]
      //cb: [ false, Validators.required ] <-- I have also tried this
    });
  }

  onSubmit(value: any) {
    console.log('Submitted: ', this.form);
  }
}
```

Comment: So what is the problem, your second version works fine `[ false, Validators.required ]`.

Comment: In the second case, for me at least, the `this.form.value` is `{ cb: false }` and `this.form.valid` is `true`

Comment: Look at the answer. `this.form.valid` is no more`true`.

Comment: Now you can use `Validators.requiredTrue`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**.ts**

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app', 
  template: `
    <h1>LOGIN</h1>
    <form [ngFormModel]="loginForm"  #fm="ngForm"  (submit)="doLogin($event)"> 

          <input type="checkbox" id="cb" ngControl="cb" #cb="ngForm" required>
          <button type="submit" [disabled]="!loginForm.valid">Log in</button>

          <br/>
              <div>Valid ={{cb.valid}}</div>
              <div>Pristine ={{cb.pristine}}</div>
              <div>Touch ={{cb.touched}}</div>
              <div>form.valid?={{loginForm.valid}}</div>
          <BR/>
          <BR/>

    </form>
    `,
  directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES,FORM_DIRECTIVES,CORE_DIRECTIVES]
})

export class Login { 
  constructor(fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.loginForm = fb.group({
      cb: [false, Validators.required],
    //cb: ['',Validators.required] - this will also work.

    });
  }
  doLogin(event) {
    console.log(this.loginForm);
    event.preventDefault();
  }
}
```

***[Working Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/3pDmddVZID6EQKLxsXKA?p=preview)***.

Please let me know if any changes required.

Comment: So two things. First off, you have `required` in the HTML which is really what I was trying to avoid. But removing it for your plnkr will still work as expected. However, the plnkr is using beta.0. If you remove the `required` in HTML and move to beta.6, this no longer works. This may be a bug with Angular.

Comment: So, after some digging around in the angular github repo, the correct fix for this is to not set the checkbox value to false, but to '' instead. So with beta.6 the correct way is `cb: ['', Validators.required]`. If you edit your answer I'll mark it as correct.

Comment: when I posted my answer without any edit, I put it with `' '`.But as you can check this also works fine with no issue. You can mark it as an aswer. I'll update it with `// cb:[' ',Validators.required]`. so other users will be able to see other ways to use `validator.required`.

Comment: You need to use `Validators.requiredTrue` for it to work properly. Otherwise if you check and un-check it will still be "valid".

Answer (score 140):

Since [Angular 2.3.1](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#231-2016-12-15) you can use [**`Validators#requiredTrue`**](https://angular.io/api/forms/Validators#requiredTrue):

***Component:***

```
this.formGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
  cb: [false, Validators.requiredTrue]
});
```

***Template:***

```
<form [formGroup]="formGroup">
  <label><input type="checkbox" formControlName="cb"> Accept it</label>
  <div style="color: red; padding-top: 0.2rem" *ngIf="formGroup.hasError('required', 'cb')">
    Required
  </div>
  <hr>
  <div>
    <button type="submit" [disabled]="formGroup.invalid">Submit</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

<kbd>[**STACKBLITZ DEMO**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gitter-aemvds)</kbd>

Comment: Validators.requiredTrue is the key!

Comment: Validators.requiredTrue didn't work for me with Angular 5

Comment: @ryanrain Please, expand why it isn't working for you.

Comment: I'm using **Angular CLI: 7.3.8**. ```Validators.requiredTrue``` is working perfectly for me. Thank you @developer033

Comment: if you have 2 checkboxes and using  `Validators.requiredTrue` , it need all checkboxes to `true`, my requirement need at least one checkbox to be `true`(if you have more than one checkbox), anyone have suggestion on how to solve this ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57895884/disable-formgroup-by-using-validators

Comment: this should be the accepted answer, use the library features instead of workarounds

Answer (score 86):

You could just use a ValidatorPattern and check for the right (boolean) value:

```
<input type="checkbox" [formControl]="myForm.controls['isTosRead']">
```

and here is the binding:

```
this.myForm = builder.group({
        isTosRead: [false, Validators.pattern('true')]
    });
```

Comment: This is the best answer imho. Also it's possible to use `formControlName="isTosRead"` rather than `[formControl]="..."`.

Comment: This is great! Works fine for me in Angular 4

Answer (score 22):

```
<h1>LOGIN</h1>
<form [formGroup]="signUpForm"> 
    <input type="checkbox" formControlName="cb">
    <button type="submit" [disabled]="!loginForm.valid" (click)="doLogin()">Log in</button>
</form>

export class Login { 
  public signUpForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.signUpForm = fb.group({
      cb: [false, Validators.requiredTrue]
    });
  }
  doLogin() {

  }
}
```

Answer (score 10):

I found that Validator.required does not work properly for checkboxes.
If you check a checkbox and then uncheck it, the FormControl will still show it as valid, even though it is unchecked. I think it only checks that you set it to something, be it true or false.

Here is a quick simple validator you can add to your FormControl:

```
  mustBeChecked(control: FormControl): {[key: string]: string} {
    if (!control.value) {
      return {mustBeCheckedError: 'Must be checked'};
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }
```

Comment: You can you `Validators.requiredTrue` instead of `Validators.required`.

Answer (score 3):

HTML Form

```
<div class="col-md-12">
                  <div class="form-group">
                      <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="agree" formControlName="agree">
                      <label class="form-check-label" for="agree">
                        I agree to our <a target="_blank" href="#">Terms of use</a> and
                        <a target="_blank" href="#">Privacy Policy</a>.
                      </label>
                      <div class="text-danger" *ngIf="(isRegSubmit||regForm.get('agree').touched) &&
                          regForm.get('agree').hasError('required')">
                          Please agree to terms of use and privacy policy.
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
```

TS File

```
  regForm: FormGroup;isRegSubmit: boolean = false;
  constructor(
    private fb: FormBuilder
  }

  this.regForm = this.fb.group({
        agree    : [false, Validators.requiredTrue]
    });
```

Validators.required not worked
Also, we can show error message by checking the value too and restrict the user to submit but it is not a good approach as we're not using validation, so whenever there is only a single checkbox then add Validators.requiredTrue instead of Validators.required

Answer (score 0):

I have this really simple example:

In your component:

```
login : FormGroup;

constructor(@Inject(FormBuilder)formBuilder : FormBuilder) {
this.login = formBuilder.group({userName: [null], password: [null],
staySignedIn: [false,Validators.pattern('true')]});
}
```

In your HTML:

```
<form [formGroup]="login" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input formControlName="userName" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input formControlName="password" type="password" required>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>
    <input formControlName="staySignedIn" checked="staySignedIn" type="checkbox"> bla
  </label>
    </div>
    <button type="submit">bla</button>
    <div >
        <a href>bla?</a>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score -1):

For Angular 8, I did it like the below for checking if atleast one checkbox is checked amongst three checkboxes

```
form = new FormGroup({
    // ...more form controls...
    myCheckboxGroup: new FormGroup({
      myCheckbox1: new FormControl(false),
      myCheckbox2: new FormControl(false),
      myCheckbox3: new FormControl(false),
    }, requireCheckboxesToBeCheckedValidator()),
    // ...more form controls...
  });
```

created a custom validator

```
import { FormGroup, ValidatorFn } from '@angular/forms';

export function requireCheckboxesToBeCheckedValidator(minRequired = 1): ValidatorFn {
  return function validate (formGroup: FormGroup) {
    let checked = 0;

    Object.keys(formGroup.controls).forEach(key => {
      const control = formGroup.controls[key];

      if (control.value === true) {
        checked ++;
      }
    });

    if (checked < minRequired) {
      return {
        requireCheckboxesToBeChecked: true,
      };
    }

    return null;
  };
}
```

and used it like below in html

```
<ng-container [formGroup]="form">
   <!-- ...more form controls... -->

   <div class="form-group" formGroupName="myCheckboxGroup">
      <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" formControlName="myCheckbox1" id="myCheckbox1">
        <label class="custom-control-label" for="myCheckbox1">Check</label>
      </div>

      <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" formControlName="myCheckbox2" id="myCheckbox2">
        <label class="custom-control-label" for="myCheckbox2">At least</label>
      </div>

      <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" formControlName="myCheckbox3" id="myCheckbox3">
        <label class="custom-control-label" for="myCheckbox3">One</label>
      </div>

      <div class="invalid-feedback" *ngIf="form.controls['myCheckboxGroup'].errors && form.controls['myCheckboxGroup'].errors.requireCheckboxesToBeChecked">At least one checkbox is required to check</div>
    </div>

    <!-- ...more form controls... -->
  </ng-container>
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are using PrimeNG, you can do it thru a TAG app-form-required-field, like this:

```
<p-checkbox name="_yes" #active="ngModel" required value="true" 
label="Active" binary="true" [(ngModel)]="filter._yes"></p-checkbox>

<p-checkbox name="_no" #inactive="ngModel" required label="Inactive" 
binary="true" [(ngModel)]="filter._no"></p-checkbox>

<app-form-required-field
     *ngIf="!filter._yes && !filter._no"
     [form]="active"
     [form]="inactive"
     id="msgAtivo"
     requiredMessage="Field required!"
>
</app-form-required-field>
```

Answer (score -1):

despite of putting validator simple check below conditions

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-form',
  directives: [FORM_DIRECTIVES],
  template: `  <form [ngFormModel]="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(form.value)">
    <input type="checkbox" id="cb" ngControl="cb">
    <button type="submit" [disabled]="!form.valid && !cb.value">
    </form>`
})
```

Answer (score -1):

**Coponent:**

```
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators, AbstractControl } from '@angular/forms';

public profileForm!: FormGroup;

constructor(
    private _fb: FormBuilder
  ) { }
  
ngOnInit(): void {
    this._createForm();
    this._setValidationRule();
}

get fc(): { [key: string]: AbstractControl } {
    return this.profileForm.controls;
  }

  private _createForm() {
    const self = this;
    self.profileForm = self._fb.group({
      required_checkbox: [false],
      zipcode: [''],
      city: [''],
      town: [''],
    });
  }
  
  private _setValidationRule() {
    const self = this;
    self.profileForm.get('required_checkbox').valueChanges.subscribe(
      ruleStatus => {
        if (ruleStatus) {
          self.profileForm.get('zipcode').setValidators(Validators.required);
          self.profileForm.get('city').setValidators(Validators.required);
          self.profileForm.get('town').setValidators(Validators.required);
        } else {
          self.profileForm.get('zipcode').setValidators(null);
          self.profileForm.get('city').setValidators(null);
          self.profileForm.get('town').setValidators(null);
        }
        self.profileForm.get('zipcode').updateValueAndValidity();
        self.profileForm.get('city').updateValueAndValidity();
        self.profileForm.get('town').updateValueAndValidity();
      });
  }
```

**Template**

```
<mat-checkbox class="terms" formControlName="required_checkbox">Pickup Riraku</mat-checkbox>
        
<mat-form-field appearance="outline">
    <mat-label>Zip Code</mat-label>
    <input matInput type="text" formControlName="zipcode" placeholder="">
</mat-form-field>

<mat-form-field appearance="outline">
    <mat-label>City</mat-label>
    <input matInput type="text" formControlName="city" placeholder="">
</mat-form-field>

<mat-form-field appearance="outline">
    <mat-label>Town</mat-label>
    <input matInput type="text" formControlName="town" placeholder="">
</mat-form-field>
```

Answer (score -1):

To set the value in a checkbox the checkbox itself can have a value or not. So you can test on `Validators.required` and pass the value or true when checked and null or false if unchecked.
And trigger the method onChangeInput : <input type="checkbox" (change)="changeInput($event)">

```js
public changeInput(event): void {
  this.isChecked = event.target.checked;
  // passing the value
  this.onChange(this.isChecked ? (this.value ? this.value : true) : false);
  // set touched
  if (!this.isTouched) {
    this.isTouched = true;
    this.onTouch();
  }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Create a method to detect any changes

```
checkValue(event: any) {
    this.formulario.patchValue({
      checkboxControlName: event.target.checked
    })
}
```

Put that method on an event change and `ngModel required` properties

```
<input (change)="checkValue($event)" type="checkbox" formControlName="checkboxControlName" value="true" ngModel required>
```

And use the convetional way to validate

```
this.formulario = new FormGroup({
  checkboxControlName: new FormControl('', [Validators.required])
});
```

[Source](https://angular.io/api/forms/CheckboxRequiredValidator)