# Angular / ionic: how to make a checkbox control invalid?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

What is a simple way to make a checkbox control invalid in an Angular Form if the checkbox is unchecked ? I'd like to do it in HTML only if possible.

Here is what I get for now:

```
<form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" #f="ngForm">

  <!-- ... -->

  <ion-item>
    <ion-label>I accept terms</ion-label>
    <ion-checkbox name="termsAccepted"
                  [(ngModel)]="termsAccepted"
                  required>
    </ion-checkbox>
  </ion-item>
</form>
```

Here, the `required` directive does not work: as soon as you check the checkbox, it's considered valid forever, even if you uncheck it then (which is a normal behaviour of `required` directive actually)

I look [there](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/#!?type=directive&query=validator) but didn't found a directive for this.

Should I right my own directive or did I miss a simpler way? Thanks.

Comment: What do you want to do if it's invalid? Do you want to show a message? Do you want to disable the submit button?

Comment: @borislemke I want to disable the submit button (I got a `[disabled]="!f.valid"` on it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checkboxes are a bit tricky here. You need to hack a bit if you want to set a particular field as invalid. You could add a change event, which passes  which would manually set the field as invalid and valid based on if it's checked or not, let's say a function called `checkIfChecked`. You also need to use ViewChild to be able to refer to your form:

```ts
import { ViewChild, NgForm } from '@angular/core';

@ViewChild('f') f: NgForm;

checkIfChecked() {
  if (this.termsAccepted == false) {
    this.f.controls.termsAccepted.setErrors({notValid:true});
  }
  else {
    this.f.controls.termsAccepted.setErrors(null);
  }      
}
```

Maybe there's a prettier way, open to suggestions ;)

---

All this would be much easier with a reactive form though, I refer to [this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39770969) where you would do the following:

```ts
this.myForm = builder.group({
    termsAccepted: [false, Validators.pattern('true')]
});
```

Comment: Excellent, thanks! I'll take a look to Reactive forms soon. Two questions: 1) I used `(click)="checkIfChecked()"`It works well but maybe it's not the one I should use?   - 2) what should be the type of the `termsAccepted` property? Thanks again :)

Comment: Glad to hear it worked! Yeah, reactive forms are good to use, the larger the form becomes, all the better the reactive form becomes. Personally if you do not have a large form, reactive form can be overkill. But this is soooo subjective, so you need to form your own opinion and what feels best in your case. Here it would definitely be easier with reactive form, so that you do not need the function above at all :) But as to your questions: I would use `click` myself in this case, since it really is a click event :) `termsAccepted` variable should be `boolean`.

Comment: Thanks for the advice ;) Sorry I just noticed the second question was completely dummy haha.

Comment: Argh we forget something. The first time the page is loaded, the control is valid but should not be. To solve this, I tried to call the checkIfChecked() method on a ngAfterViewInit() method, but I have an error: cat not read property setErrors of undefined

Comment: Seems to work if you have the `required` attribute in the checkbox. And also if you do not set initial value to `termsAccepted`, but just declare it `termsAccepted: boolean`. Seems it considers it as valid if it has an initial value set. http://plnkr.co/edit/1xwhtwB5YjKHDbRzusHP?p=preview

Comment: yes, the required attribute is a good idea, because it forces the input to be invalid as soon as the user did not click on it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

From your comment, you stated that you want to disable the submit button if it is not checked. And you want to achieve this with HTML only, so here's what I've got:

```
<button [disabled]="!f.valid || !termsAccepted">submit</button>
```

Note that you can use assignment operators inside the template `&&` and `||` will work. (I might be wrong on how you call it).

This is more of a hackery, instead of using this you might want to fix how you build your form instead. You should have a read into `ReactiveForms`, trust me, this will save you a lot of time in the future.

**UPDATE**: the `checkbox` element has no `required` state. It is valid whether it is checked or not. You might want to create a directive, something like `[mustBeChecked]` instead.

Comment: Thanks for this. From your answer, I understand that it's not possible to do this with a "Template Driven" form (except with the hacky solution), but it is possible with "Reactive" forms (that I didn't learn for now). Just one question: coding my own Angular directive for this validation could be another solution?

Comment: I just tried out something on plunker. I just realized, the `checkbox` really has no `required` state. It's state is actually valid, whether checked or not. You might want something like `[mustBeTrue]` instead to validate by checkin whether it's value is true or not.

Comment: `[mustBeTrue]` is imaginary attribute, you could create it your self to invalidate a `checkbox` element.

Comment: Argh we forget something. The first time the page is loaded, the control is valid but should not be. To solve this, I tried to call the `checkIfChecked()` method on a `ngAfterViewInit()` method, but I have an error: `cat not read property setErrors of undefined`.

Comment: Did you try by setting the initial value of `termsAccepted` to `false`? Also, you might want to do the check inside the `ngAfterViewInit` hook.

Comment: `cguAccepted` is false, but the problem is with `this.activateAccountForm.controls.cguAccepted` which is undefined.

Comment: Hold on, are you talking about `ReactiveForms` now?

Comment: Nope :) Still on template driven forms

Comment: Ohh, I thought `FormControl` is `Reactive` only. Sorry can't help you with that, I haven't used template-driven forms really :'(

Comment: oops, my mistake, I wanted to talk of this with the other answer. Sorry!

Comment: @DavidD. ohh ok lol :D Anyway, I took some time to make you this beautiful reactive form, which works perfectly for you http://plnkr.co/edit/QshP9gKNkod4V8JnFKjP?p=preview&open=app%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: Really kind thanks! I'll take a look just after my Reactive Forms lesson :)