# Angular 4 form validation with input fields and checkboxes

Tags: forms, angular, validation, typescript

I have this form right here:

```
<form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" #testForm="ngForm">

  <div class="form-group col">
    <label for="a">a</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="a" [(ngModel)]="form.a" name="a" required>
      <option value="x">x</option>
      <option value="y">y</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="b">b</label>
    <input class="form-control" id="b" [(ngModel)]="form.b" name="b" required />
  </div>

  <div class="form-check">
    <label class="form-check-label">
      <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input">c
    </label>
  </div>

  <div class="form-check">
    <label class="form-check-label">
      <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input">d
    </label>
  </div>

  <div class="col text-right">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" [disabled]="!testForm.form.valid">Submit</button>
  </div>

</form>
```

With this component-code behind:

```
export class FormComponent {
  form = new Form();
  submitted = false;
  onSubmit() {
    this.submitted = true;
  }
}
```

What I want to achieve is that my button only gets enabled, when both the dropdown and the input field are filled in, which works with the `required` attribute, AND both checkboxes are checked, which doesn't work.

My question: Is there something like `required` for Checkboxes, or are there other ways to solve this problem?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35462316/requiring-a-checkbox-to-be-checked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way:

```
 <div class="form-check">
    <label class="form-check-label">
      <input type="checkbox" [checked]="ch2" (change)="ch2= !ch2" class="form-check-input">c
    </label>
  </div>

  <div class="form-check">
    <label class="form-check-label">
      <input type="checkbox" [checked]="ch1" (change)="ch1= !ch1" class="form-check-input">d
    </label>
  </div>

  <div class="col text-right">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" [disabled]="!testForm.form.valid || !ch1 || !ch2">Submit</button>
  </div>
```

Comment: I hat to replace `&&` with `||` and now it works, thank you!

Comment: man, your request.. AND both checkboxes are checked. if you put || then with one of checkboxes checked you got true on condition.. but ok. hope i help you!

Comment: I meant it like I said it. I don't know why, but the `||` functions like an AND instead an OR in this case. Just try it your own, its strange

Comment: Wait, I got it now :D I have 4 elements a,b,c,d in my form. As soon as one is not valid the button should not be clickable. => That means both checkboxes, as well as the dorpdown and the input field must be valid, and therefor the OR is perfectly right. Its not like "Enable the button when all fields are valid", but more like "disable the button as soon as one filed is not valid".

Comment: ouh yes, disabled should be true when one of elements is false. then the good condition is !testForm.form.valid || !ch1 || !ch2 i think. can you check this?