# disable FormGroup by using Validators

Tags: angular, typescript, checkbox, formarray, formgroups

I had `formArray` checkbox on my `checkboxForm`, I need to disabled button submit if no checkbox are `checked`, I had implement custom validator on my `checkboxForm`, this is what I had tried;

**Ts file**

```
  get formReceivedSummons() {
    return this.checkboxForm.get('receivedSummons') as FormArray;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.checkboxForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      receivedSummons: this.formBuilder.array([])
    });
    this.getReceivedSummons();
  }

  getReceivedSummons() {
    this.receivedSummonsSubscription = this.inquiryStore.summons$
      .subscribe(receivedSummons => {
        this.receivedSummons = receivedSummons;
      });
  }

  addCheckboxes() {
    this.formReceivedSummons.setValue([]);
    this.formReceivedSummons.setValidators([minSelectedCheckboxes(1)]);
    this.receivedSummons.data.items.map(x => {
      this.formReceivedSummons.push(
        this.formBuilder.group({
          itemNo: [x.itemNo],
          isChecked: false,
        }));
    });
  }


function minSelectedCheckboxes(min = 1) {
  const validator: ValidatorFn = (formArray: FormArray) => {
    const totalSelected = formArray.controls
      .map(control => control.value)
      .reduce((prev, next) => (next ? prev + next : prev), 0);

    return totalSelected >= min ? null : { required: true };
  };
  return validator;
}
```

I had place validators at `formArray` which is  `this.formReceivedSummons.setValidators([minSelectedCheckboxes(1)]);`

this is what I had implement in **html file**

```
    <form [formGroup]="checkboxForm" (ngSubmit)="submitSelectedCheckbox()">
        <ng-container formArrayName="receivedSummons" *ngFor="let summon of formReceivedSummons.controls; let i = index">
            <ng-container [formGroupName]="i">
                <input type="checkbox" formControlName="isChecked"> {{summon.value.itemNo}}
      </ng-container>
    </ng-container>
    <button [disabled]="!checkboxForm .valid">submit</button>
</form>
```

my checkboxForm button have been disabled, but if I checked one `checkbox` it should be enabled, but it didnt. I'm not sure how to solve thw problems, could use some guide and guidance to solve this.

**Update**

based on my finding in google and So, this is the close I can get,

```
  addCheckboxes() {
    this.formReceivedSummons.setValue([]);
    this.receivedSummons.data.items.map(item => {
      this.formReceivedSummons.push(
        this.formBuilder.group({
          itemNo: [x.itemNo]
          isChecked: [false, Validators.requiredTrue],
        }));
    });
  }
```

by using `Validators.requiredTrue`, it need two checkboxes to be selected, then it will enable the button,but my requirement I need at least one checkbox to be select than it will enable the button submit form

Comment: The validator is working ? Invalid flag is emitten by this formgroup ?

Comment: not, the validator is not working, supposed to be, button submit disabled until I selected one of the checkbox, but it didnt

Comment: If you want an e.g. of custom validation over an array, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57794118/how-to-add-custom-validator-to-a-formarray/57794738#57794738

Comment: it is my approach is wrong ? @Eliseo

Answer (score 0):

Make something like this:

export a function. something like this:

```
export function customValdiator(form: FormGroup) {
  const formValue = form.value;
  // with the formValue apply your own validation logic .
  if (/* HAVE ERROR */) {
    return { checkboxesRequired: true };
  } else {
    return null;
  }
}
```

build your form:

```
 this.checkboxForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      receivedSummons: this.formBuilder.array([])
    },  { validator: customValdiator });
```

and remove add validators from your addCheckboxes method.

dont matter if u add or remove rows to `receivedSummons` FormArray when u change any data on the form angular will execute `customValdiator` function and pass the form as argument and you have access to current receivedSummons values for valid which is checked.

Answer (score 0):

When you are initializing the form in the constructor add the validator to the formarray first.Then after you receive the data call the `addCheckboxes` method.

```
form: FormGroup;
receivedSummons = [];

constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
   this.checkboxForm = this.formBuilder.group({
     receivedSummons: new FormArray([], minSelectedCheckboxes(1))
   });

   of(this.someMethodWhichReturnReceivedSummons()).subscribe(receivedSummons => {
      this.receivedSummons = receivedSummons;
      this.addCheckboxes();
   });
}
```

In the addCheckboxes

```
private addCheckboxes() {
    this.receivedSummons.map((o, i) => {
      const control = new FormControl(i === 0); // if first item set to true, else false
      (this.form.controls.receivedSummons as FormArray).push(control);
    });
}
```